# cvs2svn conversion at directory level

Tags: svn, tags, cvs, branch, cvs2svn

I have access to a repository that IT has created for me.
`http://oursvn_server/mysvn_repo`
I have access to the CVS files which can be accessed via 
`/proj/cvs/`

I want to convert all files/directories from /proj/cvs/* to http://oursvn_server/mysvn_repo/*

I can't do this at /proj/cvs/ level and I want to bring the directories in /proj/cvs/* over, one by one.

How is this possible?

cvs2svn -username=myname -s http://oursvn_server/mysvn_repo/dir1 /proj/cvs/dir1

I want to bring everything over, branches, tags ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what your concern was for converting at /proj/cvs? Do you want only specific folders go into SVN? I've written recently about the migration tools [here](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/06/subversion-migration-tools.html). If you can elaborate a bit on your concerns I may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The basic command would be something like

```
cvs2svn --dumpfile dumpfile.dat /proj/cvs
```

By default, cvs2svn includes all branches and tags in the conversion.  If you want to customize your conversion in other ways, cvs2svn has many other option that allow you to do so.

The above command creates an SVN dumpfile called `dumpfile.dat`.  You need local (filesystem) access to the Subversion repository to load the dumpfile into it using the `svnadmin load` command.  Thus you will have to get your IT people either to give you filesystem access to the SVN repository, or to load the dumpfile that you give them into the repository for you.

Comment: From my expirience, you can load the dumpfile directly to the server after you create an empty repository on the server.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to load a dumpfile into an SVN repository is using the "svnadmin load" command, which requires filesystem-level access to the SVN repository.  So you have to copy the dumpfile to the SVN server then run "svnadmin load" on the server.  Thus the OP cannot avoid getting help from his/her IT people.